# Can't update the symfony CLI through scoop

Tags: scoop-installer, symfony-cli

When I try to update symfony through this command:

```
scoop update symfony-cli
```

It says:

> Scoop was updated successfully!
> **symfony-cli: 5.4.12 (latest version)**
> Latest versions for all apps are installed! For more information try 'scoop status'
> Scoop is up to date.
> Everything is ok!

However, when I then do `symfony new`, I get:

> A new Symfony CLI version is available (5.4.12, currently running 5.4.2).

**UPDATE**: I think it's because I first installed symfony-cli with binaries. How do i uninstall binaries to use symfony through scoop **OR** update the binaries?
(Also, I have PHP 8.1.6.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove update protection and run update again.

```
scoop unhold symfony-cli
scoop update symfony-cli
```

If this doesn't work, you can reinstall it.

```
scoop uninstall symfony-cli
scoop install symfony-cli
```

Comment: After uninstalling, symfony is still installed. I think it's because I first installed symfony with binaries. (So I will update the question)